# How do I install Storybook along with Vue Cli 3?

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs2, storybook

I can't install [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) along with a Vue Cli 3 project. When trying to `npm run storybook` I get the error:

> not find module
>   '@storybook/vue/dist/server/config/defaults/webpack.config.js'

This happens *-I think-* because webpack is now an internal part of Vue Cli since version 3.

I've tried several tutorials and configurations like [this](https://medium.com/@almeynman/setup-vue-with-storybook-using-vue-cli-3-0-typescript-example-1be64a7cc7ac), [this](https://github.com/davestaab/vue-cli3-storybook) and [this](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/3267), with the same or similar errors related Webpack.

**How can I run Storybook along with Vue Cli 3?**

Answer (score 3):

You can just run `vue add storybook`

https://github.com/storybooks/vue-cli-plugin-storybook